# Need to display array in selectbox option in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

I need help in displaying an array of cities in a selectbox as options. Do note every selecbox is in a dynamic row in an order form. Can't get the result in selectbox on a trigger. Help!

** city_data is a array of Cities.
** '+row+' is a row of product (because we can add multiple products and its cities)

- When tried useing this line in my code it shows all cities in a text box but I want all cities into select box as options.

  $('input[name="city_data'+row+'"]').attr('value', ui.item['city_data']);
- I had tried this code as well but no use..I know i am missing something very tiny!

  $('select[name="city_data'+row+'"]').attr('value', ui.item['city_data']);

## Code:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $('input[name="product_name' + row + '"]').attr('value', ui.item['product_id']);
    $('input[name="model' + row + '"]').attr('value', ui.item['model']);

    $('input[name="city_data' + row + '"]').attr('value', ui.item['city_data']);

    updateTotal(row);
}
```

Comment: Add jQuery as tag pls ;) And i really dont what, what you want to do... do you want to know how to create the options for the selectbox?